# Постоянные соединения с БД (PHP). Как это работает?

Tags: php, база-данных

PHP, запускаясь и отрабатывая, "умирает". Такова его механика работы. И во многом это, прям , круто. Безопасно. Однако тут вопрос. Как это все работает с соединением с БД? Если на сайте хайлоад, то каждый новый запрос из браузера будет делать новое соединение с БД (ведь все скрипты выполняются заново)? Такой сайт явно долго не проживет, верно? Я нашел статью в документации, где описывается возможность создания постоянного соединения. Но тогда соединение станет разделяемым ресурсом. Кто позаботится о синхронизации доступа к нему?
Прошу гуру PHP, читающих данный пост помочь разобраться в данном вопросе. Опишите, пожалуйста, как будет работать PHP nginx php-fpm на достаточно нагруженном проекте (масштаба пикабушечки например), как быть с этим постоянным соединением и кто тогда разруливает параллельный доступ запущенных PHP процессов к нему. Спасибо!

Comment: Не уверен, что постоянное соединение это хорошее решение. Не уверен, что сайт ляжет от пусть даже от большого количества соединений. Ваш скрипт соединится отработает и закроет коннект. Это не самые затратные операции, на запросы у вас уйдет больше ресурсов и времени выполнения. Ну это ИМХО, посижу почитаю, что папки напишут)

Comment: Вижу, что по дефолту в том же постгресе какое-то смешное количество одновременных соединений доступно. 100 вроде. А что если у меня распродажа и в новый год все равнули на мой сайт? И одновременно сидит на сайте население небольшого города. Ну или хуже, правительство США на моем сайте лотерею гринкарт решило проводить.

Comment: Ну даже 100 "одновременных" соединений это не самый плохое значение. При правильном проектировании ваши php скрипты будут упираться только в скорость выполнения расположенных в них запросов и промежуточных php операций. При нормальном - доли секунд и соединение закроется. Т.е. вам в доли секунд нужно 100 соединений поймать.  Постоянное соединение будет занимать память постоянно + другие проблемы. Кмк это шило на мыло.

Comment: Ну и что что распродажа? Нормальный пхп скрипт отрабатывает 0.01  секунды. то есть в секунду можно обслужить 100 человек на одном соединении. учитывая, что человек нормальный, а не придурок какой-нибудь, то он делает запрос не раз в секунду, а ну хотя бы в 5. итого на одном соединении мы можем обслужить 500 человек. На на сотне - 5000. На тысяче - 50000.

Comment: Надо понимать, что из этих 0.01 само соединение занимает ничтожную часть времени. Это просто для понимания микроскопичности масштаба "проблемы". при том что у вас скорее всего скрипт отрабатывает не 0.01, а 0.5 в лучшем случае. или вообще по 5 секунд под нагрузкой из-за блокировок данных в БД например. И вот этими проблемами и надо заниматься, ускоряя  то что действительно медленно работает.

Comment: Вот после тыясчи одновременных соединений мускуль начнет загибаться, и вот там надо будет искать другие решения. Но сначала надо в них упереться. И опять же - пконнект никак здесь не поможет, 1000 соединений так и останется 1000, с постоянным коннектом, или без

Answer (score 3):

Часто используют пул-соединения, например pgbouncer для PostgreSQL, есть и другие аналоги для MySQL, MSSQL, etc.

Comment: только не надо путать pull и pool, так что по-русски обычно пишут пул

Comment: @Ипатьев поправил, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

> Такой сайт явно долго не проживет, верно?

Нет. Живут и процветают.

Это типичный пример умозрительных построений на неизвестных величинах. Рассуждение уровня "В рыбе содержится ртуть и мышьяк. Если есть рыбу, то отравишься и умрёшь".  Начинающие программисты особенно склонны к таким фантазиям, не имеющим ничего общего с реальностью.

Коннект к БД не настолько ужасно невероятно чудовищно тяжёлая в плане потребления ресурсов операция. И наш нубский сайт сначала сто раз упадет из-за неоптимального SQL, кривых алгоритмов, блокировок и еще примерно миллиона причин, перед тем как упереться в скорость коннекта.

Способ есть, но у него есть как достоинства так и недостатки. И в 99% случаев недостатки перевешивают достоинства. В мускуле это pconnect. Причем в ПДО он реализован криво, новый скрипт не очищает состояние коннекта - то есть в нем могут оказаться незавершенные транзакции, неснятые блокировки, и т.д.
Mysqli в этом плане лучше, но и профит меньше - потому что такая очистка и занимает львиную долю того времени, которое экономит постоянное соединение.

> Но тогда соединение станет разделяемым ресурсом.

Не станет

> кто тогда разруливает параллельный доступ запущенных PHP процессов к
> нему.

фпм и разруливает. у каждого треда своё соединение. один тред всегда обслуживает одно соединение с веб-сервером, то есть никакого параллельного использования коннектов не будет.